# Выровнять иконки по уровню текста

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть группа ссылок, где перед каждой ссылкой, в виде изображения, добавлен favicon этого сайта, на который стоит ссылка. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: Блок ссылок]

***Вопрос*** - Как мне выровнять иконки по уровню текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding-bottom:1em;

Answer (score 1):

Может [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/395eh/) подойдет?

Comment: Спс, сейчас гляну..

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой путь:
Находим div в котором лежит этот блок. Допустим он называется "contain".
Пишем.

```
.contain img {
    position:relative;
    bottom:10px; //* На глаз скажу, что надо где-то 10-15px*//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай ссылку в одном блоке в виде -

**<a href="#">*<img src="#"> потом текст нужный*</a>**

Если картинка такого же размера, как и шрифт - то всё будет ровно.

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, но он не дал ожидаемого результата.

Comment: А ты таблицей не думал сделать ?

Comment: хорошая идея, сейчас попробую...

Comment: Плохая идея.

Answer (score 0):

[так](http://jsfiddle.net/t2x67/1/) тоже не катит??

Answer (score 0):

А не пробовал сделать это через `<ul>` и просто изменить `<li>` стиль?